# Playing video from FFMpeg command in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, avfoundation

In iOS, We can make a video composition with video track, audio track and some complex stuffs with AVComposition and we are able to play that with AVPlayer directly without writing that composition to a video file.

Well, it is possible to make a similar composition of video with FFMpeg command in Android. It is also possible to stream from the command. My question is, can we play the output of a FFMpeg command in Android Media Player like playing a AVComposition in iOS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if FFMpeg can do output into HTTP stream, then it should be easy to play it from URL.

Comment: I need help on the same question. I want to preview the output instead of processing the output and then preview it.

Comment: @akashvarlani It may be possible but will require time and a lot trial errors. I tried it at that time, I could stream from android phone to PC and play with FFPlay. But wasn't able to do the same within Android app itself. So, I had to took the easy route, i,e writing the changes in video because I didn't have much time.

Comment: @ayon thanks for the quick response. We are at the same stage. I also did streaming from android to PC but cannot stream the same within the app. If you can help, i will pay you for that.